# Why I am getting two different results for the same design?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, design-patterns, logic

Quick question:

I have a bunch (cloud) of coordinates and I tend to find the four corner coordinates of the whole bunch. And by corner I mean:

> MyDesiredResult = { SmallestX, BiggestY, BiggestX, SmallestY }

I use this **Old Routine** to get my values and it **is the CORRECT ONE**:

```
double smallestX = MyCloud[0].X;       // assing X of first element to my result controller
var tempCoordPoint = MyCloud[0];       // assign first element to my result controller

for (int i = 0; i < MyCloud.Count; i++)
{
    if (smallestX > MyCloud[i].X)      // find minimum X
    {
        smallestX = MyCloud[i].X;
        tempCoordPoint = MyCloud[i];
    }
}

MyResult.Add(tempCoordPoint);           // add to my list
```

However, I would need to do that **Four Times** (for the Four results). So I am trying to optimize my code by changing it to this **New Routine** which I use only once:

```
List<CoordPoint> MySortedList = MyCloud.Select(c => new CoordPoint { X = c.X, Y = c.Y, Z = c.Z, Color = c.Color }).ToList();

MySortedList.Sort((c1, c2) => c1.X.CompareTo(c2.X));     // sort on X
var temp = MySortedList[MySortedList.Count - 1];         // hold biggest X in a temp variable
MyResult.Add(MySortedList[0]);                           // add smallest X to my result

MySortedList.Sort((c1, c2) => c1.Y.CompareTo(c2.Y)); ;   // sort on Y
MyResult.Add(MySortedList[MySortedList.Count - 1]);      // add biggest Y to my result 
MyResult.Add(temp);                                      // add biggest X to my result
MyResult.Add(MySortedList[0]);                           // add smallest Y to my result
```

But it gives different results. I would want to show a sample input, current output and a desired output. I can skip the sample input (huge load) and show the results. Could anyone point me towards what I am doing wrong?

For the same input:

**Result From Old Routine**:

> (0, 4), (15, 12), (23, 6), (19, 0)

**Result From New Routine**:

> (0, 4), (18, 12), (23, 6), (18, 0)

[image]

Comment: You've stated that two different code snippets produce different results, but have said nothing about what the correct results are.

Comment: @Servy I did. See before the result part "_P.S The old routine is the correct one!_". And the New Routine should not result in different results! This is the problem.

Comment: The fundamental premise of your question shouldn't be in a post script.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit my post. But you know, I think I have a better discussion. I just noticed that both results are valid..  Since both are in the form of  `{ SmallestX, BiggestY, BiggestX, SmallestY }`. But how could I solve my problem in finding the correct corner points using the new routine which is simpler? Ehm ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your question with another question:

What happens if two points have the same Y coordinate and that Y coordinate happens to be the minimum or maximum?  Likewise for the X coordinate?

Let me illustrate with an example.  Let's say you had these 4 points:

> (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)

Your original algorithm would return:

> (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)

Now let's say we took those original 4 points and shuffled them:

> (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)

If you run your original algorithm on that, you'll get this:

> (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)

According to you, the original algorithm is correct, but I've just given it the same set of points in two different orders and gotten two different answers.  So which of the answers is correct?  What is the actual expected result?

Now, there's a reason I didn't provide the results of your new algorithm and that's because I don't know what your new algorithm would produce.  The reason why I don't know is that `List<T>.Sort` performs an unstable sort.  That means that two elements that compare "equal" will not necessarily be left in order.  So, if our input was `(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)` all of the following are valid possibilities after trying to sort by X coordinate:

> (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)
>
> (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)
>
> (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)
>
> (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)

`List<T>.Sort` could produce any one of those.  If you have more duplicate X coordinates, you'll have even more possible orderings.  The reason this is called unstable is because the relative order of two equal elements (e.g. `(0, 0)` and `(0, 1)`) is not preserved after sorting.  The sorting algorithm might swap their positions.

Comment: I knew what are you going to ask before I continued reading :D I was just thinking about it. You are right.. Good catch! +1 and thank you. Please allow me some time for other answers though, I think I will need to take the largest `X` for cases like `Y`s are equal and largest `Y` if `X`s are equal and so on. Working on it

Comment: @FirstStep That depends on what you're actually trying to do with these points. If you're just trying to get the corners of the bounding box, then you'll need to create new points because a set of points won't necessarily contain points at the corners of its bounding box. Consider `(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)`; the corners are `(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)`, none of which are in the input set.

Comment: Well I might disagree with you on that one. I am exactly trying to get the contour. And getting the bounds coordinates will allow me to create my contour. The coordinates of the contour would be `(XFromSmallestXCoord, YFromHighestYCoord), (XfromHighestXCoord, YFromHighestYCoord), (XFromHighestXCoord, YFromHighestXCoord ), (XFromSmallestXCoord, YFromSmallestYCoordinate)` but then, we go straight to the problem. Which is for example what if we have SeveralSmallestXCoordinate and so on. And I think it worn't matter any more.

Comment: @FirstStep It sounds like what you're actually after is the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), which your algorithm still won't do correctly.  Fortunately, there are many well published algorithms for computing the convex hull.